# Incompatible types when assigning to type ‘typedef from type ‘uint8_t’

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am running across a problem with typedefs.

```
typedef char cool_array_t[ARRAY_SIZE];

cool_array_t* out;
// do stuff with out
cool_array_t test = *out;
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> incompatible types when assigning to type ‘cool_array_t’ from type
>   ‘char *’

I tried casting out to cool_array_t but it gives the following error:

> error: cast specifies array type

Comment: `memcpy(&test, out, sizeof test);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign to arrays. You need to use `memcpy` or a wrapping `struct`.

```
struct cool_array_t {
    char data[ARRAY_SIZE];
};

struct cool_array_t* out;
// do stuff with out
struct cool_array_t test = *out;
```